# Allow iframe with https adress in https site

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, http-headers

I have webapp (written in java) that uses https. We have to show an iframe at one point with another  https adress. The problem is that various browsers won't show the iframe in https due to security concerns.

I have tried to solve this for IE by setting a header in the response to: 
X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://abc.def.com

For all other browsers i have set the header to:
Content-Security-Policy script-src 'self' https://abc.def.com; frame-src 'self'  https://abc.def.com;

https://abc.def.com is the iframe adress in this example.
How can I solve this problem to show my https if ram in my https site?

UPDATE:
The problem was that the site being iframed used a self signed certificate for https and not a real one. When switching to a real one the above solution worked.

Comment: You need to explain what exactly you mean by `various browsers won't show the iframe in https due to security concerns.` Browsers don't mind if you embed a HTTPS frame inside ANY page, unless that frame declares that you may not frame it.

Comment: The page being framed doesn't have any headers that forbids it being framed. Its being framed by other services but the framed page have now been switched to https instead of http. Browsers behaves different when showing security releated messages. Chrome shows a sad smily. IE shows various warnings depending on version. In version 8 its a yellow toolbar at top that warns you, in version 10 its a pop up in the bottom of the page.

Comment: What **exactly** does it "warn you"? Does it warn you about "mixed content" or a bad certificate, or ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the site being iframed used a self signed certificate for https and not a real one. When switching to a real one the above solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM in the header, try X-Frame-Options ALLOW

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` is a header that prevents framing. Per the OP, he's not sending that at all. Even if he were, the proper directive would be `Allow-From`.